# SQL query to select column1 value multiple times based on column 2 value

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I write a query for below scenario in Oracle?

**Input**

```
Column1 Column2
R        1
S        2
F        3
```

**Output**

RSSFFF

**i.e.** 'R' 1 time, 'S' 2 time and 'F' 3 times.

Comment: What query have you tried so far?

Comment: My actual requirement is very complex, and this is a part of that. i am not getting any idea to implement this. if you can suggest any approach or can provide any Hints, i can write the query.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rpad` to repeat the letters, and `listagg` to concatenate them in a single line, like so.

```
select
  listagg(rpad(column1,column2,column1)) within group (order by column2)
from table_name;
```

But this would work if you have another column to order the rows, in this case, I just use the `column2`.

Comment: @Ganesh I edited my answer to remove the extra `order by` clause, which would work without it.

Answer (score 2):

One method uses `lpad()`:

```
select lpad(column1, column2, column1)
from t;
```

If you want a single string, then use `listagg()`:

```
select listagg(lpad(column1, column2, column1)) within group (order by null)
from t;
```